# LMAX disruptor: How to control the speed of producers?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I recently used the LMAX Disruptor framework. How to get the number of tasks that have not been completed? If consumers consume too slowly, I want to control the production speed of producers.Does the disruptor have this function? Or how can I achieve it myself?

And I looked at the source code.
The message is stored in an array called entries.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected final E elementAt(long sequence)
    {
        return (E) UNSAFE.getObject(entries, REF_ARRAY_BASE + ((sequence & indexMask) << REF_ELEMENT_SHIFT));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are built in [wait strategies](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/docs/com/lmax/disruptor/class-use/WaitStrategy.html) for handling slow consumers.